# Importing backed up private key, gpg: [don't know]: partial length invalid for packet type 20

Tags: git, encryption, gnupg, git-secret

I've imported a private key that I've backed up on my Macbook, however, I get this message when I try to decrypt the files that were encrypted using the public key paired with my own private key.

I'm not quite sure what the message means, I am not able to decrypt my own files

What I did:

```
gpg --output test --decrypt CompletedList.csv.secret
```

What I got:

```
gpg: [don't know]: partial length invalid for packet type 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Check first the output of `gpg -vvd --output test --decrypt CompletedList.csv.secret` in order to get more details.

Check also:

- your version of GPG (considering gpg1 vs. gpg2 might not [be compatible](https://superuser.com/questions/655246/are-gnupg-1-and-gnupg-2-compatible-with-each-other)), and
- [its configuration](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Options.html#GPG-Options) (`~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`) for any peculiar setting.